# searchbox.getPlaces() is not a function from angular-google-maps searchbox

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui

I am trying to follow the searchbox example from the [angular-google-maps github repo](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/master/example/assets/scripts/controllers/search-box.js).

When my [callback](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/master/example/assets/scripts/controllers/search-box.js#L96) is called the line `places = searchBox.getPlaces()` fails with `searchbox.getPlaces() is not a function`.

I log out `searchbox`'s ownPropertyNames and get this:

```
  ["__e3_", "gm_accessors_", "autocomplete", "gm_bindings_", "visible"]
```

Sure enough, `searchbox.getPlaces()` is not a function!

My code is written in Typescript and very different in style to the example, so it is difficult to paste my actual failing code, but maybe someone could give me a pointer as to what I am getting back from the directive and why it doesn't have a `getPlaces` function please?

Comment: Any resolution after 2 years?